# Scrolling a list with jQuery animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

The below code is my attempt at animating a list of items. However, everything except the animation is working how it should. Anytime i click it moves the list items by 80 pixels but its not animated at all. What am i doing wrong?

```
$('#nav_up').on('click', function() {
    $('#block_nav ul').animate({
        top: $('#block_nav ul').offset({top: $('#block_nav ul').offset().top - 80})
    }, 'slow');
});
```

UPDATE: link to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/75SN4/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your jQuery code as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nav_up').on('click', function() {
        $('#block_nav ul').animate({ top: '-=80' }, 'slow');
        console.log($('#block_nav ul').offset());
    });
});
```

See a working [**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/75SN4/2/).

Comment: I updated my post with a link to jsfiddle. I hope this helps! http://jsfiddle.net/75SN4/1/